# How exactly to use node-sass with create-react-app 2 efficiently?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

So, with `create-react-app`@v1, I used to write `gulp` tasks to minify and compile SASS, which was not in real time, but now in `create-react-app`@v2, Facebook has supported `node-sass` to compile and reflect changes in real-time. So, my question is that

> With node-sass, where do I put my `styles.scss`?

I've tried to put it in `index.html`, but it's not working, so perhaps index.js will solve the problem?

> Will CRA2 minify my SASS in `styles.min.css` once I `npm run build` ?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes I read the docs, but no where it mentions how to minify your complied css, generally I use `cssnano` for minifying.

Comment: Did you actually try it? Following the documentation by importing a SCSS file and seeing if it compiles and minifies on `npm run build`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Not yet, I'll make a dummy for it, but the post processing shows that CSS is not minified https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/post-processing-css

Comment: You should try it. Making a new `create-react-app`, updating the `App.css` to `App.scss` and updating the `browserslist` in `package.json` compiles, minifies and post-processes the CSS. Try it `"last 2 versions"` and `"> 5%"` for `browserslist` with something like `display:flex`, it will add the necessary browser prefixes. The point is, just try it next time before, half of your questions would have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your styles in `/src/App.scss`, and update `src/App.js` (the top-level JS file/index) to include `App.scss` instead of `.css`. This will cause CRA to automatically compile/post-process the SCSS.

See also: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

Comment: So, it's okay to put my all `_sass.scss` files in one directory and then `@import` them in top-level `_styles.scss`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's common to make a `/styles` directory (or `sass`, or `css`) and import the files there from the top-level `App.scss`. It should automatically minify the css too, per https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/post-processing-css